# How to update Google Play Developer API version to v3?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Got this warning while publishing the app:

```
We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play Developer API. From December 1 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API will no longer be available. Update to version 3 before this date.
```

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html

I'm wondering why I got this warning as I'm not using Google Play developer API explicitly.

Can anyone tell me what does it mean and how to update it to v3?
The above link is not enough to solve the issue.

Upgrade every library to it's latest version already!!

[Here is the snap of libraries I've used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJyIW.png)

Comment: Maybe one of your libraries uses it. Do you mint posting your libraries?

Comment: added the screenshot of libraries, please check @ChrisPapantonis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had to update google-services.

See https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-08-22 : "The google-services plugin for Android (v4.3.1) is now available. This release removes calls to a deprecated API. For more information, refer to the Firebase Android SDK Release Notes."

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Could you please provide more information what you exactly did with firebase to update to the proper version?

Comment: In your project `build.gradle`, update your plugin version. eg `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'`