# Google play devloper API v2 to v3 how to update?

Tags: android, google-play-console

We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play Developer API. From December 1 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API will no longer be available. Update to version 3 before this date.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html

I'm wondering why I got this warning as I'm not using Google Play developer API explicitly.

Can anyone tell me what does it mean and how to update it to v3? The above link is not enough to solve the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update Google Play Developer API version to v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033386/how-to-update-google-play-developer-api-version-to-v3)